# how to convert timestamp into hoursminandsec in java

Tags: java

I have a unix timestamp. I wanted to convert into hours,min and seconds.I wanted to acheive it in java.I tried this .But I am not sure how do i have to concatenate it to hours+min+sec

```
int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(timeStamp);        
             long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(timeStamp) - (day *24);
             long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(timeStamp) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(timeStamp)* 60);
             long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(timeStamp) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(timeStamp) *60);
```

thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: Try: `Date date = new Date ();
date.setTime((long)unix_time*1000);`

Comment: A unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds since the epoch. You know that there are 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour. Do you understand how to calculate the number of hours contained in a given number of seconds?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Calendar` class for this. You can format the time using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date ();
date.setTime((long)unix_time*1000);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a",Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```